# AseComnection Open method call exception from C#

Tags: c#, database-connection, sybase, sap-ase

I am using Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient dll to connect to Sybase db from c# code. But sometimes (very rarely) I am getting an exception in the call of Open method of AseConnection class. -
Exception message is 
Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have seen this before, but with Entity Framework (a conceptual model built on top of ADO.NET) and MS SQL Server. I found the answer by Erik Funkenbusch to be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695408/inconsitency-error-inside-entity-framework-collection-was-modified-enumerati

Comment: I am not using any foreach loop. It's a simple call to Open method of AseConnection class and the exception is thrown by Open method itself